# create new dataframe from old one by applying an interpolation function on two rows with non-numeric values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, interpolation, apply

I have a dataframe with some missing rows. I would like to select 2 rows (selection is done separately) and interpolate the values between these two rows. If I generate x rows within these two rows, I would like to repeat the values of two end rows down to the mid point. Columns are non-numeric values and I essentially copy the values of the columns of one of the rows. 
for example if I have the following rows : 
my old value dataframe is :

```
df_old : 
   fname    lname     occupation
0   Alex    Schapiro    teacher
1   paul    Gorman       nurse
```

I wrote a function that takes a column (with 2 values)called data_col and a list of new points to generate values for them (called new_x). it finds the mid point in the list (new_x) and repeats the first value of the column up to mid point, and repeats the second value of the column from mid point to the end of the list length. the result will be a list of values generated.

```
def generate_object_dtype(data_col,new_x):
    new_val = []
    mid_tp = middle(new_x)
    new_val.extend([data_col.iloc[0]]*sum(i <= mid_tp for i in new_x))
    new_val.extend([data_col.iloc[1]]*sum(i > mid_tp for i in new_x))

    return(new_val)



function to find mid point of the list :
def middle(a):
    a = sorted(a)
    l = len(a)

    if len(a) % 2 == 0.:
        m = (a[int(l / 2)] + a[int(l / 2) - 1]) / 2.
    else:
        if l < 2:
            m = a[0]
        else:
            m = a[int(l / 2)]

    return m
```

Now, I apply the generate function on my old_df to create a new df with interpolated rows for non-numeric column values:

```
    >>old_data.apply(lambda col: generate_object_dtype(col, new_x), axis=0) 

fname                     [Alex, Alex, paul, paul]
lname         [Schapiro, Schapiro, Gorman, Gorman]
occupation        [teacher, teacher, nurse, nurse]
dtype: object
```

the result is a series of lists. I need the result to be a dataframe like this : 
new_df :

```
   fname    lname     occupation
0   Alex    Schapiro    teacher
1   Alex    Schapiro    teacher
2   paul    Gorman       nurse
3   paul    Gorman       nurse
```

How can I do this?
ps. in general, is it correct to apply a function to a dataframe where the result is a new dataframe with completely new values :
i.e.

```
new_df = old_df.apply(lambda col: generate_object_dtype(col, new_x), axis=0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you perhaps show the original `DataFrame` with the missing rows? That problem can be solved with interpolate. Otherwise from the looks of it it's just a repeat problem.

Comment: df_old is my original dataframe :
   fname    lname     occupation
0   Alex    Schapiro    teacher
1   paul    Gorman       nurse

Comment: Well then what exactly is `new_x`? Also, how do you want to hand the case where you have 2 values that you need to interpolate between 5 points?

Comment: new_x is a list of new indices to be created. for example in this case             
     new_x =  [1, 2, 3, 4]                                                                                                               I could also just give it a value (number of rows) to be created rather than a list of the row indices. i always interpolate between two points. I have 2 rows a and b in my original dataframe and would like to generate number of rows between a and b using the values in a and b as explained above. Thanks!

Comment: I understand that, it's just hard to see what `between` means when you literally have sequential indices in your original `DataFrame`. And the solution to this problem depends heavily on exactly what `new_x` is. Is it always a range beginning at 1? Does it begin at 0? Can it be 15-19? This problem is easily solved if `new_x` is always np.arange(0,nrows,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take your statement, that you can just provide it with a `number of rows`.

```
import numpy as np

nrows = 4
new_x = np.arange(0, nrows, 1)

# Make sure the index begins at 0, in case you slice from another part of the `df`
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

# Move the second value to the midpoint
df.index = df.index*nrows//2

# Fill the missing values forward
df = df.reindex(new_x).ffill()
```

Output:

```
  fname     lname occupation
0  Alex  Schapiro    teacher
1  Alex  Schapiro    teacher
2  paul    Gorman      nurse
3  paul    Gorman      nurse
```

If you have an odd number of rows, this will repeat the latter row 1 more time. With `nrows=5`

```
  fname     lname occupation
0  Alex  Schapiro    teacher
1  Alex  Schapiro    teacher
2  paul    Gorman      nurse
3  paul    Gorman      nurse
4  paul    Gorman      nurse
```

You can change this to repeat the first value the extra time by modifying the index as:

```
if nrows%2:
    df.index = df.index*(nrows//2+1)
else:
    df.index = df.index*nrows//2
```

which will then output:

```
  fname     lname occupation
0  Alex  Schapiro    teacher
1  Alex  Schapiro    teacher
2  Alex  Schapiro    teacher
3  paul    Gorman      nurse
4  paul    Gorman      nurse
```